# Open a new HTML page with PHP and populate HTML page with string

Tags: php, python, html, fgets

I am running a python script inside my PHP file to do some analysis. After, "fgets" is used to extract the output and store the extraction in a string variable.

What I am trying to do:

-I have an echo statement in my PHP file that outputs a button called "Full analysis." When a user clicks on that button, I want to open up a new page on a new tab and the new page will contain the output stored on the string variable.

Is this possible? I've tried searching around and not getting much luck. Could you guys point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Edit:

Code to run python script:

```
$output= popen("python param1 param2 " 2>&1", "r");
if ($output) {
    while (($line = fgets($output)) !== false) {
          #echo $line;
          $str_var .= $line . '<br>';
    }
    if ($str_var  == ""){
         $str_var = "ERR: ";
     }
}else{
   $analysis_output = "Cannot run $str_var ";
 }
  fclose($output);
}
```

PHP code to out a button using HTML:

```
echo "<pre><a target='_blank' href='http://" . param . "'>" . "<button>" .  "More info" . "</button>" ."<a/>\n";
```

Comment: You must store the value somewhere in a database or session variable, please show your code so someone can give example.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I have added more information in my edit. Thank you.

Comment: or as a hidden variable in a form, and your "more info" button submits that form with target=_blank.  The form target page script renders the more detailed results

Comment: @DaveS, Thanks. So based on what you said, I need to create a .php script that will echo the $output variable? Then, have the newly created .php script be my action = "newlycreatedscript.php" ?

Comment: Yes, page 1 includes a form (with no visible UI just hidden variables?), link submits that form to newlycreatedscript.php, that page uses the hidden variables to render the more info page.

Comment: @DaveS Than you, it worked perfectly.